# bash: recognize $HOME in a string from CSV, then use it in a variable as valid path

Tags: linux, bash, shell, path

I am trying to make a script that reads couples of filepath `(source,destination)` from a CSV file, then copies the `source` file to the `destination` path. The CSV file for now contains only the following line:

```
./vim/vimrc,$HOME/.vimrc
```

I wrote this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
INPUT=destinations.csv
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=','
[ ! -f $INPUT ] && { echo "$INPUT file not found"; exit 99; }
while read src dest
do
    cp $src $dest
done < $INPUT
IFS=$OLDIFS
```

but nothing is actually copied. It only works when I substitute  `/home/username`  instead of `$HOME` into the CSV file, but it is exactly what I want to avoid to do. So, I cannot parse/expand `$HOME` to make it usable by the script as a valid path. Any suggestion?

Comment: What `echo "$HOME"`show in a terminal? Add `echo "$src $dest"` before `cp` or run the script with `bash -x script` to see execution details.

Comment: `cp "$src" "${dst/#'$HOME/'/$HOME/}"` ?

Comment: Good thing this doesn't work! Imagine if you could put `$(rm -rf /)` in a file and any bash script that tried to read from it would start deleting the system! My suggestion is not allowing variables at all, and instead optionally replace a leading `~` with the user's home dir. Alternatively, you can run the file through `envsubst`

Comment: @thatotherguy that's true... but if I put ~ instead of $HOME, how could I parse it to make it usable as home path?

Comment: You would write logic in your script to
 check for it and replace it.

Answer (score 0):

I’m assuming you only need to expand simple shell variables:

- You don’t need advanced parameter expansion using curly braces, such as arrays `${VAR[@]}` or replacements `${VAR/x/y}`
- You don’t rely on backslashes to escape characters
- You don’t use the double dollar sign `$$`
- The *value* of your variables don’t contain dollar signs (but their variable *name* is preceded by a dollar sign, obviously)

The following function is a simplistic variable expander, limited by the above assumptions:

```
expand_vars() {
  mapfile -t variables < <(grep -Po '(?<=\$)[_A-Za-z][_0-9A-Za-z]*' <<< $1 | sort -u)
  for v in "${variables[@]}"
  do
    set -- "${1//\$$v/${!v}}"
  done
  printf -- '%s' "$1"
}
```

This function grabs every `VAR` into your `$VAR` occurrences and replaces them with their corresponding value.

The `mapfile` command will assign the list of variable names to the array `variables`. For your example:

- This array should contain no values for `src`
- This array should contain one value for `dest`, i.e. `HOME`

The replacement is done into `"${1//\$$v/${!v}}"`

- For your example, `v` would have the value `HOME`
- Thus the replacement is equivalent to `"${1//\$HOME/$HOME}"`
- Resulting in the replacement of `\$HOME` by `$HOME`
- Because the backslash protects variable expansion, `\$HOME` matches the raw string dollar `$` followed by `HOME`, whereas `$HOME` (unprotected by backslash) is considered as a variable that will be expanded

You may then call this function for every variable read from the CSV that you’d like to expand. Your copy would then become:

```
cp "$(expand_vars "$src")" "$(expand_vars "$dest")"
```

I strongly recommend putting variables into double-quotes to avoid issues with whitespace characters.